# Android Studio: Click TextView to open an Specific Image on other Activity (Click Index Title to Open page on other Activity)

Tags: android-studio

I m Developing Book Reading Project on Android studio, it has index activity with all titles and page numbers, when some one click on any title of index so on the an other activity the specific image should be open. all images are in Drawable folder. 
here is XML Coding of First Activity coding Activity_main3.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
android:gravity="center"
android:shrinkColumns="1">

<TableRow
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"


   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ناشر پاران...5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="پنهنجي پاران...6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>
```

The Second Activty coding is like this Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.sindhila.www.sindhi_school_linguistics.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SwitchImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:text="Next"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/SwitchImage2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/SwitchImage2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/pic3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SwitchImage2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:text="Previous"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/SwitchImage" />
```

and Here is Coding Of mainactivity.java 
it has two buttons for next and previous page and an image view to open images from drawable folder

```js
 package org.sindhila.www.sindhi_school_linguistics;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;



import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Locale;

import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;





public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static ImageView imageView;
    private static Button SwitchImage;
    private static Button SwitchImage2;






    //
    PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher;
////

    private int current_image_index;
    int images[] = {R.mipmap.pic1, R.mipmap.pic2, R.mipmap.pic3,
            R.mipmap.pic4,
            R.mipmap.pic5,
            R.mipmap.pic6,
            R.mipmap.pic7,
            R.mipmap.pic8,
            R.mipmap.pic9,
            R.mipmap.pic10,
            R.mipmap.pic11,
            R.mipmap.pic12,
            R.mipmap.pic13,
            R.mipmap.pic14,
            R.mipmap.pic15,
            R.mipmap.pic16,
            R.mipmap.pic17,
            R.mipmap.pic18,
            R.mipmap.pic19,
            R.mipmap.pic20,
            R.mipmap.pic21,
            R.mipmap.pic22,
            R.mipmap.pic23,
            R.mipmap.pic24,
            R.mipmap.pic25,
            R.mipmap.pic26,
            R.mipmap.pic27,
            R.mipmap.pic28,
            R.mipmap.pic29,
            R.mipmap.pic30,
            R.mipmap.pic31,
            R.mipmap.pic32,
            R.mipmap.pic33,
            R.mipmap.pic34,
            R.mipmap.pic35,
            R.mipmap.pic36,
            R.mipmap.pic37,
            R.mipmap.pic38,
            R.mipmap.pic39,
            R.mipmap.pic40,
            R.mipmap.pic41,
            R.mipmap.pic42,
            R.mipmap.pic43,
            R.mipmap.pic44,
            R.mipmap.pic45,
            R.mipmap.pic46,
            R.mipmap.pic47,
            R.mipmap.pic48,
            R.mipmap.pic49,
            R.mipmap.pic50,
            R.mipmap.pic51,
            R.mipmap.pic52,
            R.mipmap.pic53,
            R.mipmap.pic54,
            R.mipmap.pic55,
            R.mipmap.pic56,
            R.mipmap.pic57,
            R.mipmap.pic58,
            R.mipmap.pic59,
            R.mipmap.pic60,
            R.mipmap.pic61,
            R.mipmap.pic62,
            R.mipmap.pic63,
            R.mipmap.pic64,
            R.mipmap.pic65,
            R.mipmap.pic66,
            R.mipmap.pic67,
            R.mipmap.pic68,
            R.mipmap.pic69,
            R.mipmap.pic70,
            R.mipmap.pic71,
            R.mipmap.pic72,
            R.mipmap.pic73,
            R.mipmap.pic74,
            R.mipmap.pic75,
            R.mipmap.pic76,
            R.mipmap.pic77,
            R.mipmap.pic78,
            R.mipmap.pic79,
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonClick();
        buttonClick2();









//////
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.pic1);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);

        photoViewAttacher.update();
//////

    }


    public void buttonClick() {

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        SwitchImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SwitchImage);
        SwitchImage.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        current_image_index++;
                        current_image_index = current_image_index % images.length;
                        imageView.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
                    }
                }
        );


    }

    public void buttonClick2() {

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        SwitchImage2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SwitchImage2);
        SwitchImage2.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       if (current_image_index!=0) {
                           current_image_index--;
                           current_image_index = current_image_index % images.length;
                           imageView.setImageResource(images[current_image_index]);
                       }
                    }
                }
        );
    }




}
```

Every thing is working Fine, i need to have hyperlink on Textview (on Activity_main3.xml and Main3Activity.java) to open specific image on Activity_main.xml/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

```
i have used following Coding but it produce error how to solve it please help. i want to click a textview on one activity and open specific image on other activity in imageview
```

in xml file of first activity  in textview i added

```
    android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
```

.... added coding to first index activity named Main3activity.java   where textviews are placed when I click textview it should open other activity and an image in it

```js
 public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("pic", pic4.png);
        startActivity(intent);

    } ...
```

and this coding to mainactivity.java  where image should be opened in image view

```js
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonClick();
        buttonClick2();

        setContentView(R.mipmap.pic1);


        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("img", 0));
```